# Facebook API real-time friends' online presence update

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I'm currently developing an app in facebook which has a list of my friends and shows their online presence. To get this, I used:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '".$this->user_id."')";
$active = $this->facebook->api(array(
  'method' => 'fql.query',
  'query' =>$fql
));
```

But since I'm only getting this information (status, online presence) at the time when I open my app, it'll not change until I reload my app.

My question is, how can I get a real-time update of status-change or online-presence change by my friends?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to do that query periodically, or use an XMPP (Jabber) connection to get updates in real-time.

Comment: Well, yeah. You either have to keep checking, or hook into XMPP and have the updates sent to you.

Comment: What about the [`friends_online_presence`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission?

Comment: Please note, XMPP is going to be removed from Facebook in 2015.

Comment: @BrianRoach Per my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222641/fetch-online-presence-for-thousands-of-facebook-app-users) I heard from Facebook directly that you can't currently subscribe to online_presence and they have no plans to make that possible. Do you think there's a different way to use XMPP to get this info?