# Facebook - Possible to get the friends_online_presence with the graph Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the `friends_online_presence` with the Facebook Graph-Api?

When I request this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,inbox,friends_online_presence&access_token=XXXXXXXX
```

I get the error `"message": "Unknown fields: friends_online_presence"` [Facebook-Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`friends_online_presence` is the name of the permission needed to access the online presence, but the actual method to retrieve it is different. In FQL this should work:
`select online_presence from user where uid in (select uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Note that there's an open bug report about most users' statuses not being available; I"m unsure as to the status of that bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129383637170749

If you directly integrate with Facebook's XMPP servers (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) that might be more useful for your use-case depending on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can query the API with FQL (Facebook Query Language).

See this thread - [Facebook API real-time friends' online presence update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295829/facebook-api-real-time-friends-online-presence-update)