# Real-time update the online_presence for a user's friends, using FQL/Chat API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, xmpp, facebook-fql, facebook-chat

I'm currently developing an app in facebook which has a list of friends of the user logged in and shows their online presence. To get this, I used the following FQL query:

`SELECT name,uid, online_presence  FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

`friends_online_presence` is an extended permission and returns the Facebook Chat status (a string, one of active, idle, offline or error).

My question is how can I get a real-time update of online-presence change by my friends?

***Option 1:*** *Query the Facebook API periodically, in a background process*
***Option 2:*** *Hook into XMPP to get real-time updates ( an answer from duplicate question below)*.

People have asked this question before here too, here are some duplicates(unsolved):
[facebook-api-real-time-friends-online-presence-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295829/facebook-api-real-time-friends-online-presence-update)  &
[Is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-user-online-presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697243/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-user-online-presence?rq=1).

I wanted to know if someone has solved the problem and if yes, how did you solve it.

It'd be great if you could elaborate a bit about the *Option 2* (using XMPP/Jabber), because I feel periodically querying would suffice for only a while, when the user count is less.

Comment: I've accepted the only answer, because if I don't and the bounty gets over, I'll not be able to accept any answer for this question.

Comment: I'll work on the only answer provided, but still open for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use XMPP.

For integrating facebook chat via XMPP, I think the best way in Rails would be

1. Rails + [StropheJS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)
2. In addition to this, you could include something like [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) (but that's not a necessity)

Overall, the system would look like

> [StropheJS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) (client side JS)   ----> [XMPP BOSH Manager](http://metajack.im/2008/09/08/which-bosh-server-do-you-need/) ([eJabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) / [Punjab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab)) ----> Facebook
>   Servers

In addition to all this, if you are new to XMPP then the book ["Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470540710) is worth a read and has lots of examples with strophejs

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your answer doesn't really get me anywhere. Can you explain in detail, may be list down some steps that'll get my job done quick.

Comment: @JatinGanhotra Here is a blog post, which talks about setting up this (with the ruby gem xmpp4r) http://siddharth-ravichandran.com/2011/01/21/multiuser-chat-using-xmpp-and-orbited-using-ruby-on-rails/  . I plan to write down all the steps necessary, but that would take time. Will update the answer soon. Also check if this helps http://www.slideshare.net/ca168168/realtime-webwithrailsxmpp

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'll start off with this, and wait for your updated answer meanwhile.

Comment: I'm giving my bounty rep to you, will be waiting for your updated answer and any help possible. Since yours is the only answer, if I don't award it to you, my bounty rep would be lost, not doing any of us good. :)

Comment: @JatinGanhotra :) Thanks. Plan to do it soon.

Comment: @Nishant Per my question here (stackoverflow.com/questions/27222641/…) I heard from Facebook directly that you can't currently subscribe to online_presence and they have no plans to make that possible. Do you think there's a different way to use XMPP to get this info?