# Is x-facebook-platform (facebook chat) xmpp server usage changed after 24.04.2013? (All users presence received offline)

Tags: xmpp, facebook-chat, user-presence

I am currently developing facebook chat clients on multiple platforms;

- Web: PHP [Jaxl 3.x](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL),
- iOS: Objective-C [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework),
- Android: Asmack (<:)>Can't remember which one there are several smack forks and at first i stormed between nearly all of them. < /:)>)

Since 24.04.2013 none of them receive presence as "available" for currently online users, instead "offline" presence is returned. I double-checked with FQL using the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295829/facebook-api-real-time-friends-online-presence-update) and it is working perfectly on FQL (side note for some: without XMPP connection).

I can receive only available presence over XMPP(JABBER) client, when i receive message.

Any idea on the subject? Am i missing something server connection, API version, etc?.. Seriously, all 3 of them gone and i am currently praying for 1 of them to work, then i can blame myself and encourage myself to fix the issue... :)

Comment: I am using JAXL and can confirm that it works with user and password but not with AppSecret and AccessToken, so it is some change on Facebook's side.

Comment: Thanks @IvanBaldo for your comment, you were right. I guess they are testing something. As of today 30.04.2013 presence data working as expected. <:)> Still curious about new feature... </:)>